# CPOpenPanel not working in Cappuccino

Tags: cappuccino

I am trying to use CPOpenPanel to select a file for upload,
when I call runModal upon CPOpenPanel object , it is throwing an exception as 
CPInvalidArgumentException: - [CPOpenPanel runModel] unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x005585

Does CPOpenPanel still has bugs in cappuccino framework ?
Am I missing something ? I just created an object and calling runModal on that object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CPOpenPanel only works in our NativeHost environment, not the the browser. The same for CPSavePanel. Those are about the only classes this is true for.

Answer (score 0):

The error show you that the runModel doesn't exist for CPopenPanel. it's not runModel but runModal, and If you want to upload a file look at 
this thread https://groups.google.com/forum/m/?fromgroups#!topic/objectivej/6ZupNuR5DIw

It's about 2 libs for uploading file with a simple button or drag and drop upload.

Ben

Comment: Ya that was my mistake, but runModal also does not work. I think its not yet implemented in Cappuccino .

Answer (score 0):

This should work with NativeHost (jake run-desktop):

```
var panel = [[CPOpenPanel alloc] init]; 
[panel runModal];
```